# gridsearchCV for linear regression

Tags: python

I am having a difficult using gridCVsearch code for different linear models.

I get errors at the same stage for each model.
For example, my codes for Linear Regression is as below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
lr_pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearRegression())
lr_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
lr_pipe.score(X_test, y_test)
param_grid = {'n_neighbors': range(1, 10)}
grid = GridSearchCV(lr_pipe, param_grid, cv=10)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid.best_params_)
print(grid.score(X_test, y_test))
```

I get error at the step "grid.fit(X_train, y_train)" with a message:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter n_neighbors for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('standardscaler',
             StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)),
            ('linearregression',
             LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None,
                              normalize=False))],
     verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

What did i do wrong in my coding? i followed exactly the general codings for gridsearchCV.

Comment: As the error states, LinearRegression in sklearn doesn't have a parameter `n_neighbors`. See [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) for what parameters it does take. (StandardScaler also doesn't take that parameter)

Comment: How do you import n_neighbors? below code does not seem to work:
from sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor import n_neighbors

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. That's kind of like asking how to use the steering wheel of a car to make a mince pie. You just...don't. If you want to use a neighborhood-based model, you need to choose [one of the available neighbors algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html). If you want to use linear regression, then you would use the parameters for a linear regression, which has no in-built functionality for neighborhoods.